# What is the most optimistic perspective of room-temperature solid-state QC?

Tags: architecture, solid-state

I've read the "*trend*" article entitled [Is a room-temperature, solid-state quantum computer mere fantasy?](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v2/34) from almost 10 years ago, and was wondering if things have really changed: What is the current consensus on the viability of a room-temperature solid-state quantum computer?

Comment: Could we persuade you to flesh our your question a bit more? What "things" in particular are you wondering might have "changed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Articles on technology from 10 years ago are often outdated, to some extent the same can be said of last year's information. Occasionally something will stand for decades, or fall into decline only to be revisited later.

The most optimistic perspective is: someone is working on it.

Here are some more recent articles on room temperature QC:

"[Room-temperature single-photon emitters in titanium dioxide optical defects](https://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjnano/articles/9/100)" by Chung, Leung, To, Djurišić and Tomljenovic-Hanic (04 Apr 2018).

"[Room temperature high-fidelity non-adiabatic holonomic quantum computation on solid-state spins in Nitrogen-Vacancy centers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07293)" by Yan, Chen, and Lu (20 Dec 2017).

"[Scalable quantum computation based on quantum actuated nuclear-spin decoherence-free qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08567)", by Rong, Dong, Geng, Shi, Li, Duan, and Du (27 Dec 2016).

"[Coherent control of single spins in silicon carbide at room temperature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0180)" by Widmann, Lee, Rendler, and 15 others (31 Oct 2014).

Lots of people are working on the idea, how soon it becomes available remains to be seen. Use of solid-state could be on the way out ...

"[Practical spin wave transistor one step closer](https://phys.org/news/2018-03-transistor-closer.html)" physics.Org article, March 1, 2018, and University of Groningen "[Magnon spintronics in non-collinear magnetic insulator/metal heterostructures](https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/publications/magnon-spintronics-in-noncollinear-magnetic-insulatormetal-heterostructures(6ec15eb7-2d85-4c48-b953-ac23aff19e07).html)" (Feb 2017).

[image: Magnon Circuit]