# Which temperature has been the highest to achieve a quantum logic operation?

Tags: solid-state

My question is somehow related with a previous one: [What is the most optimistic perspective of room-temperature solid-state QC?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/what-is-the-most-optimistic-perspective-of-room-temperature-solid-state-qc).

---

Regarding solid-state qubits,

- What is the highest temperature at which the simplest quantum logic operation has been performed?  Let's say: initialization, arbitrary rotation and measuring, repeated to have enough statistics in order to verify a good fidelity. In which solid-state system has this happened?

Answer (score 1):

I think your reference has the answer: nitrogen vacancy centers in diamond, where you can do one qubit gates at room temperature. In fact, even higher temperatures are possible, but you will have to play a tradeoff between fidelity and temperature at some point.

That said, NV centers are not scalable, and I don't think more than 2 qubits will ever be really possible due to the physical problems with interacting immobile NV centers which are randomly distributed.

Comment: You are probably right, but phosphorus in silicon has also been shown to operate at room temperature, right? http://science.sciencemag.org/content/342/6160/830.full So the question would be: how high have people gone? (Or has no one ventured beyond RT?)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write diamond, not silicon. Yes, the principle of using defects in insulators/semiconductors is very general,  silicon works as well. The $T_1$ for the systems is very long (minutes), but the phase coherence is not nearly as long. I'm sure someone has tried higher than room temp, but again I think the gate fidelity just gets very low.

Comment: Let me see do some research on higher than room temp systems and get back to you.